# Realizar operacion con operador extraido de formulario

Tags: php

estoy iniciandome en php y al realizar una calculadora mediante formularios de html me encuentro con el siguiente problema.

Tengo un formulario con 3 campos.
Dos son de tipo "number" para introducir los dos operando de la operacion.
El otro campo es un "select" con las distintas operaciones a realizar (suma, resta, division y multiplicacion.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Calculadora</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <form method="POST" action="calculadora.php">
            <input type="number" name="operando1">
            <input type="number" name="operando2">
            <select name="operacion">
                <option value=+ selected="selected"> Sumar(+)</option>
                <option value=-> Restar (-)</option>
                <option value=*> Multiplicar (*) </option>
                <option value=//> Dividir (/) </option> </select> <input type="submit" name="=" value="=" />

        </form>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Mi idea era extraer las variables en el archivo php operar de tal manera

```html
<?php
        $resultado = $_POST['operando1']$_POST['operacion']$_POST['operando2'];

        echo $resultado;
    ?>
```

Siendo operando 1 y 2 los values de los campos donde se introduciran los numeros, y operación el value de la operación seleccionada.

Esto me da un error de unexpected variable.
Se que se puede hacer con un switch, pero quiero saber si hay posibilidad de hacerlo así ya que me parece mas simple.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No, no se puede hacer asi. Creo que ningun lenguaje pega variables asi, porque no sabe que hacer con las mismas. Tene en cuenta que el contenido de esas variables (suponiendo que pudieras pegarlas), no se va a ejecutar. Si fuera asi, el sistema como sabria cuando parar?

Comment: Podrías pero no debes. Lo que estás tratando es de generar código dinámicamente. Lo podrías hacer usando la función eval y concatenando los operandos y las operaciones, pero está altamente desaconsejado, y si es un ejercicio, seguramente tu profesor te hará rehacerlo por otros métodos, como por ejemplo el que tu dices del switch. https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.eval.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe una manera de conseguir lo que necesitas. Esta pasa por hacerlo a través de la función `eval()`. Esta función es muy peligrosa, ya que se considera un **ENORME** agujero de seguridad debido a que lo que la función reciba como parámetro de entrada se va a ejeutar como si fuese código **PHP**, por lo que te recomiendo usar un `switch` para identificar el operando y montar la operación dependiendo de este.

> **Precaución**
>
> El constructor de lenguaje **eval()** es muy peligroso porque permite la
>   ejecución de código de **PHP** arbitrario. Su uso está totalmente
>   desaconsejado. Si se ha verificado cuidadosamente que no existe otra
>   opción que usar este constructor, se ha de poner especial atención en
>   no pasar ninguna información proporcionada por el usuario a esta
>   función sin haberla validado apropiadamente con anterioridad.

No obstante te pongo un ejemplo de como se haría con `eval()`:

```
$operando1 = 1;
$operando2 = 2;
$operador = '+';

$resultado = eval($operando1 . $operador . $operando2);

echo ($resultado);
```

Comment: OP, si tiras por la vía del eval, tienes por lo menos que "sanear" la entrada para asegurarte que la entrada sea siempre numérica y que no te estén metiendo código php en esos input. Poner que el input sea de tipo number no es suficiente. Échale un vistazo a https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.filter-var.php y https://www.php.net/manual/es/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Answer (score 1):

Lo que intentas hacer no es lo mas recomendable, ya que como te han dicho anteriormente, usar eval sería un gran riesgo de seguridad para tu aplicación.

Lo que puedes hacer es poner un valor a tus select, y mediante un switch o if else if hacer tus operaciones.

Ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Calculadora</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <form method="POST" action="calculadora.php">
            <input type="number" name="operando1">
            <input type="number" name="operando2">
            <select name="operacion">
                <option>Sumar</option>
                <option>Restar</option>
                <option>Multiplicar</option>
                <option>Dividir</option>
            </select>
            
            <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Calcular" />

        </form>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

y en el archivo calculadora.php deberás poner lo siguiente:

```
    <?php

        if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){

            $valor1 = $_POST['operando1'];
            $valor2 = $_POST['operando2'];
            $operacion = $_POST['operacion'];


            if($operacion=='Sumar'){

                echo "La suma de $valor1 más $valor2 es " . ($valor1 + $valor2);

            }else if($operacion=='Restar'){

                echo "La resta de $valor1 menos $valor2 es " . ($valor1 - $valor2);

            }else if($operacion=='Multiplicar'){

                echo "La multiplicación de $valor1 por $valor2 es " . ($valor1 * $valor2);

            }else if($operacion=='Dividir'){

                echo "La división de $valor1 entre $valor2 es " . ($valor1 / $valor2);

            }else{

                echo 'error';

            }



        }


?>
```